# Can't use Android shell atrace command because of write access

Tags: android, shell, adb

If I try **atrace** tool from **adb** shell in **emulator**:

```
# atrace
atrace
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite: No such file or direc
tory (2)
```

If I do :

```
#mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug
#mount: No such file or directory
```

If I try to make the folder :

```
#mkdir -p /sys/kernel/debug
#mkdir failed for /sys/kernel/debug/, No such file or directory
```

So apparently I don't have write access even if I'm **root**....

**Edit:**

I can create folder in **/data/** path but no in **/sys/** path...

Has anybody be able to create folder in **/sys/** path in emulator environment?

Any help ?

Thanks !

Comment: I suspect that atrace requires a kernel option that is not available in the emulator build. "No such file or directory" should really mean does not exist. "Permission denied" would be the case that requires permissions. You also can't create directories in the sys-fs. It is an interface provided by the kernel, not a "real" filesystem

Comment: Thank you! I've created some folders in /data folder but I can't create folders in /sys folder... Do you know if it is a "emulator configuration" problem or I will need to recompile Android's Platform Code in order to have this option available?

Comment: Yes, it is a configuration problem. `atrace` seems to be intended for device manufacturers, linux kernel developers, ... but not app developer. So atrace support is not enabled in the emulator. You would need to recompile the platform and specifically the kernel. The kernel can be compiled with different configurations and you need to enable some debug options. http://lwn.net/Articles/365835/ is very similar

Comment: show the output of 'mount' command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the provided emulator this is not possible because Linux kernel compilation was done without activating TRACING OPTIONS.

In order to be able, it is necessarily to recompile Linux kernel activating the required options.

Steps can be found here:

http://www.linuxforu.com/2010/11/kernel-tracing-with-ftrace-part-1/

P.S. Thanks to @zapl and other involved guys.

Regards,