# Systrace |No /sys/kernel/debug/tracing directory on Android 4.1.1(Galaxy S3 I747UCDLK3)

Tags: android, performance, linux-kernel, systrace

I'm trying to use Android systrace tool with my galaxy S3 and I meet some problem seems to be the kernel problem.

I have follow the steps described in this post: [Failed to use systrace in Jelly Bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11618755/failed-to-use-systrace-in-jelly-bean)

I'm able to "mount -t debugfs nodev /sys/kernel/debug", and here's the result of "mount" command:

```
255|root@android:/ # mount
rootfs / rootfs ro,relatime 0 0
tmpfs /dev tmpfs rw,nosuid,relatime,mode=755 0 0
devpts /dev/pts devpts rw,relatime,mode=600 0 0
proc /proc proc rw,relatime 0 0
sysfs /sys sysfs rw,relatime 0 0
none /acct cgroup rw,relatime,cpuacct 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/asec tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
tmpfs /mnt/obb tmpfs rw,relatime,mode=755,gid=1000 0 0
none /dev/cpuctl cgroup rw,relatime,cpu 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/system /system ext4 ro,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/userdata /data ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,journal_async_commit,data=ordered,noauto_da_alloc,discard 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/cache /cache ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/persist /persist ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/modem /firmware vfat ro,relatime,gid=1000,fmask=0006,dmask=0006,allow_utime=0020,codepage=cp437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro 0 0
/dev/block/platform/msm_sdcc.1/by-name/efs /efs ext4 rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
/dev/fuse /storage/sdcard0 fuse rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,user_id=1023,group_id=1023,default_permissions,allow_other 0 0
nodev /sys/kernel/debug debugfs rw,relatime 0 0
```

So I guess debugfs is mounted to the system.
However, I couldn't find /sys/kernel/debug/tracing directory where ftrace is supposed to lies in. So here's the errors I got when I use "atrace" command in adb shell:

```
root@android:/ # atrace
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_wakeup/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/power/cpu_frequency/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/power/cpu_idle/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_clock: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/workqueue/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/ext4/ext4_sync_file_enter/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/ext4/ext4_sync_file_exit/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_rq_issue/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_rq_complete/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on: No such file or directory (2)
error: unable to start trace
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/tracing_on: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/options/overwrite: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_switch/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/sched/sched_wakeup/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/power/cpu_frequency/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/trace_clock: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/workqueue/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/ext4/ext4_sync_file_enter/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/ext4/ext4_sync_file_exit/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_rq_issue/enable: No such file or directory (2)
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/events/block/block_rq_complete/enable: No such file or directory (2)
unable to start tracing
error opening /sys/kernel/debug/tracing/buffer_size_kb: No such file or directory (2)
```

I've glanced several posts on stackoverflow, in this post ([Can't use Android shell atrace command because of write access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13515879/cant-use-android-shell-atrace-command-because-of-write-access)) an answer suggest to recompile the kernel. DO we really have to do that to use the systrace tool?

Also an answer in this post ([Unable to run systrace tool on android emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16167626/unable-to-run-systrace-tool-on-android-emulator)) mentioned Samsung GS3 can actually use systrace. I'm wondering if I have been doing something wrong here.

Comment: Somewhat related but it should be the same on Android: "If you are unable to see the tracing subdirectory, you will need to enable tracing in the kernel configuration, and recompile it." [Source](http://www.linuxforu.com/2010/11/kernel-tracing-with-ftrace-part-1/)